# Convert simple dropdown menu from jQuery to pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

This is the simple dropdown menu made in jquery, i need to make it in regular JavaScript 
with no jQuery. Can someone help me do that i lack experience.

Here's the live example http://jsfiddle.net/qRBuN/ It has multilevel navigation, but i it does not have to have it, just one simple drop down and it does not need no animation either.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("ul.topnav li a").mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").stop(true, true).slideDown('slow').show();

        });  

        $("ul.topnav li.first_level").mouseleave(function(){ 
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").stop(true, true).slideUp('fast');
        });

        $("li.ex_level a").mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).parent().find("ul.ex_subnav").stop(true, true).slideDown('fast').show();
        });

        $(".ex_level").mouseleave(function(){ 
            $(this).parent().find("ul.ex_subnav").stop(true, true).slideUp('fast');
        });
    });

</script>
```

===

```
   <ul class="topnav">  
        <li><a href="="#">Home</a></li>  
        <li class="first_level">  
            <a href="="#">One</a>  
            <ul class="subnav">  
                <li><a href="#">One</a></li>  
                <li class="ex_level"><a href="#">Two</a>
                    <ul class="ex_subnav">
                        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>  
                    </ul>  
                </li>  
                <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>  
            </ul>
        </li>  

        <li class="first_level">  
            <a href="="#">One</a>  
            <ul class="subnav">  
                <li><a href="#">One</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Two</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li> 
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>  
    </ul>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use jQuery for this?

Comment: I dont like the fact that its 100KB in size.

Comment: It's 32kB and it can be cached very well too. Definitely worth it considering how much cross browser madness it takes away ;-)

Comment: @Jack I'm with Jack... Unless you are targeting dial-up users 32kb is nothing.  Make sure you are using the minified version instead of the Development version.  I'm assuming that is what is causing your 100kb size.

Comment: Actually, it looks like 1.7.2 minified is 92kb now.  Still this is nothing for the average persons connection.  Are you wanting to keep the user from having to download the file or keep your server from having to serve the file?

Comment: Before giving up on using such a great tool, make sure you do all your research. You're going to create a lot of pain for yourself, your clients, your successor, and everyone else who is wondering why it takes you 10 years to make a simple update to a website. See http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/ for more information.

Comment: Also, search for Google pagespeed. If you're having speed issues with your website, let that tool analyze it so you don't make too many crazy guesses. :)

Comment: I suggest developing in the development version of jQuery, build your code, then crush all scripts afterwards with Closure Compiler. As Google advertises, Closure strips unused code. That should give you one massively stripped version of jQuery and your script.

Comment: @Jared it's 92kB minified, after gzip it becomes 32kB =D

Comment: Ok i'll try Closure Compiler, but its just makes no sense for me to use jquery if all i need is simple dropdown menu, i already figured out how to do it its basic by default dropdowns display="none" onmouseover this.dropdown.style.display="inline" thats it. its like 2 lines of code literally so what's the point to load all that jquerry? it's indeed 92KB packed.  And also it slow down slow computers and phones (yes jquery works on my android fine) with bunch of useless operations. Ye i love sliders, but i just dont need it for anything else.

Comment: @redacted jquery takes care of a lot of cross browser issues that pure javascript has to be coded to handle.  I honestly cannot think of a single mobile device that will bog down that much if any based on 92kb (assuming compression is off as mentioned by Jack).  I haven't done enough pure javascript to be able to tell you if what you are trying to accomplish will run into any issues due to cross browser support being different.

Comment: any good designer checks his work in every browser and adjust's it. anyway its my choice to use javascript.